# how can I create this gradient in photoshop?

Tags: gradient

I want to create a radar like the one bellow,
where the gradient goes darker and darker clockwise.
in the left it is totally transparent, while in the right it goes to 60%.

I tried to add linear gradients, to overlap more of them to create a similar effect, but it just doesn't look good enough. How would you do it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GD!  As evidenced by the first answer on your question, there is already a resident "Ryan".  Would you mind changing your display name so we can easily differentiate between you?  Something simple like adding an initial would do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

1. Draw a circular marquee
2. Drag guidelines over the horizontal midpoint and vertical midpoint
3. Create an "Angle Gradient" using Black to Transparent starting at the center you now have.
4. Adjust opacity so that the darkest side is how you want it
5. Use a soft eraser at a very large size compared to the image and lightly erase outside of the "lighter" side of the gradient
6. Add a yellowish line over the hard angle with some blur to it

If you're not after that yellowish line with the blur on it then just go in and smooth it out with brush and eraser.

Comment: A suggestion: Shape layers may be more appropriate than bitmap layers, especially if it's for mobile or iOS dev, where Retina and non-Retina images will be required.

Comment: I've never made an app before but my understanding is that its going to be a .png or .bmp otherwise an .svg (especially if it is coded). Since we're talking about photoshop and not illustrator that eliminates the .svg option. PNG and BMP of course being raster. Do you save .eps files from photoshop (checking off the box to include vector data) and then bring those directly into apps?

Answer (score 0):

Create a rectangular document.

Make a gradient dark grey (not black) to white, from left to right.

Select the bottom 1/3 of the document, and clear to white. You should have a layer with a gradient as the top 2/3 and white on the bottom 1/3.

Filter->distort->polar coordinates.

select all, Invert colors, and use resultant layer with setting "lighten only"